# Error Trying to get property of non-object when downloading and parsing json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am trying to print out the field name: entity name and getting an error saying "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
$accrdNo = '3001044';

$url = "http://localhost:8080/webservice/index.php?id=$accrdNo";

$client = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($client);

$encoded = json_encode($result, true);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded, true);

echo $decoded->{'va_entity_name'};
```

Comment: This field I am trying to display is from these json results:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to Get Property of non-object in PHP JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666312/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-php-json)